# Splitting time entries from one table, depending on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table containing start and end times for certain processes, and a second table containing start and end times of breaks. I would like to generate a new view containing single entries for every process, without the breaks. I'll try to explain with an example:

Table one:

```
Process     |  START                |  STOP
Process xy  |  2020-08-18 08:00:00  |  2020-08-18 10:00:00
```

Table two:

```
         |  pause_START          |  pause_STOP
Break 1  |  2020-08-18 08:20:00  |  2020-08-18 08:40:00
Break 2  |  2020-08-18 09:20:00  |  2020-08-18 09:40:00
```

Desired output:

```
Process     |  START                |  STOP
Process xy  |  2020-08-18 08:00:00  |  2020-08-18 08:20:00
Process xy  |  2020-08-18 08:40:00  |  2020-08-18 09:20:00
Process xy  |  2020-08-18 09:40:00  |  2020-08-18 10:00:00
```

or visually:

[image]

---

I managed to do it if there is up to **one** break per entry with a combination of selects and unions, but this doesn't work if there's more than one break per process.

First I created `View1` like this:

> ```
> SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Table1.Process, dbo.Table1.START, dbo.Table1.STOP
> FROM            dbo.Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
>                         dbo.Table2 ON dbo.Table1.START <= dbo.Table2.pause_START AND (dbo.Table1.STOP >= dbo.Table2.pause_START OR
>                         dbo.Table1.STOP IS NULL) AND ((dbo.Table1.STOP >= dbo.Table2.pause_STOP OR
>                         dbo.Table1.STOP IS NULL) AND dbo.Table1.START <= dbo.Table2.pause_STOP OR
>                         dbo.Table2.pause_STOP IS NULL)
> WHERE        (dbo.Table1.START > CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)) OR
>                         (dbo.Table1.STOP IS NOT NULL)
> ```

And then I got the intervals like this:

> ```
> SELECT        dbo.View1.Process, dbo.View1.START AS 'start', View1_1.pause_START AS 'stop', dbo.View1.TAB, dbo.View1.MA_ID
> FROM            dbo.View1 INNER JOIN
>                        dbo.View1 AS View1_1 ON dbo.View1.Process = View1_1.Process AND dbo.View1.TAB = View1_1.TAB
> WHERE        (View1_1.pause_START IS NOT NULL)
> UNION
> SELECT        dbo.View1.Process, dbo.View1.pause_STOP, View1_1.STOP, dbo.View1.TAB, dbo.View1.MA_ID
> FROM            dbo.View1 INNER JOIN
>                        dbo.View1 AS View1_1 ON dbo.View1.Process = View1_1.Process AND dbo.View1.TAB = View1_1.TAB
> WHERE        (View1_1.pause_START IS NOT NULL)
> UNION
> SELECT        dbo.View1.Process, dbo.View1.START, View1_1.STOP, dbo.View1.TAB, dbo.View1.MA_ID
> FROM            dbo.View1 INNER JOIN
>                        dbo.View1 AS View1_1 ON dbo.View1.Process = View1_1.Process AND dbo.View1.TAB = View1_1.TAB
> WHERE        (View1_1.pause_START IS NULL)
> ```

But as I mentioned, this does not work for more than one break per interval.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Does the first table have more than one row?  Are the breaks specific to processes?

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes Table 1 has more than one line, this was just an example :) the breaks are specific to processes (in the sense that there is no break **outisde** of a process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the breaks don't overlap and are always between the start and stop (as in your example), then combine the different periods using `union all`:

```
-- first record
select t1.process, t1.start, min(t2.start) as end
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2
group by t1.process, t1.start
union all
-- all the breaks
select t1.process, t2.start, t2.end
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2
union all
-- all the in-between times
select process, starttime, endtime
from (select t1.process, t2.end as starttime, lead(t2.start) over (partition by t1.process order by t1.start) as endtime
      from table1 t1 cross join
           table2 t2
     ) t
where endtime is not null
union all
-- last record
select t1.process, max(t2.end), t1.end
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2
group by t1.process, t1.start;
```

This should work for the data in your question.  Your actual situation might be more complicated (overlapping breaks, multiple rows per process in `table2` or whatever).  If so, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct: The breaks don't overlap and they are always between start and stop of one of the processes from Table 1. After the code though you write "multiple rows per process in ```table2``` ", and that would be exactly the case I'm looking to solve.